# What is the best way to homogenize full datas between Magento or Prestashop and others platforms?

Tags: magento, prestashop

Administrators of several e-commerce sites based on Magento and PrestaShop, we wish an automate broadcasting of all information (products, customers, orders ...) to other platforms (cdiscount, amazon, counted software, social networks. ..)
There is the default Magento module but that seems to be limited to products and customers,
There are there other modules or other means to link Magento and Prestashop to other platforms?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lengow.com](http://www.lengow.com/) solution. There are existing modules both for Magento and Prestashop to link your shop to many marketplaces.